# k-sort an array in O(n log k)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

My problem is my lack of ideas for this task.

We call an array A[1 . . . n] k-sorted if it can be divided into k blocks of size n/k. So that for each block all elements contained in it are larger than all elements from previous blocks. The elements within a block do not have to be sorted.

Design an algorithm that k-sorts arbitrary arrays. The input array is to be permuted so that it is k-sorted afterwards. The parameter k is given to your
algorithm as input. Your algorithm shall take `O(n log k)` time.

I would be happy if someone could help me with this task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you talk us through what you've tried so far, what's worked, and what you're stuck on?

Comment: The key algorithm for solving this problem is [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: @user3386109 it depends. quickselect has O(n^2) worst-case performance.

Comment: @n. True, average case for quick select is O(n), and worst case is O(n^2). Whether you have a better solution that you're choosing not to share is something only you know.

Comment: @user3386109 I don't have a solution because I don't know what the problem is. Developing an O(n log k) worst-case-performance algorithm is one problem and developing an O(n log k) average-case-performance algorithm is a different problem.

Comment: (cont'd) There seems to be a way to run quickselect in O(n) worst case by using say a median-of-medians pivot selection, but the constant factor is significantly worse. So an O(n) worst-case algo is not necessarily better than an O(n) average-case algo. It depends on what kind of performance is required.

Comment: @n. Pivot selection is covered in the [variants section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Variants) of the article that I linked. And you are correct that median-of-medians is one of the pivot selection methods.